# What is a "mixed graph"?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I'm working on a digraph problem in which bidirectional edges need to be treated separately.  As such, we could consider them as undirected edges.  Clearly, if I replace bidirectional edges with undirected edges I get a ``mixed graph'' (one with directed and undirected edges).  But can a mixed graph have bidirectional edges in addition to undirected edges?  Can a mixed graph have a directed edge and an undirected edge between two vertices?

The [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29#Mixed_graph) is not crystal clear on this.  A paper, [Enumeration of Mixed Graphs](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2035390) indicates bidirectional and parallel mixed edges are disallowed.  The definition in [this article](http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/talks/ams05.pdf) claims that the ``complete mixed graph'' has a undirected and bidirectional edge between both vertices.

> What are ``mixed graphs'' typically defined as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was always my impression that a mixed graph was graph where some edges were directional and others non-directional. There are directional and non-directional graphs, so logically, a mixed would contain both?

Also, I always thought bidirectional edges are the SAME as undirected edges, as undirected edges mean you can go either way, there are not restrictions. I think it's just semantics. If you have all your other nodes connected by directional edges, then a bidirectional edge for one exclusive set of two nodes is just logical.